# Multivariable calculus, area of $x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}} \leq 4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question from a test, for multivariable calculus:

Calculate the area of
$x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}} \leq 4$

The answer should be 24pi, but how do I reach that?
If possible without using Green's theorem.

Comment: is it allow to use Green Thm?

Comment: Draw a picture.  We can revert to one variable calculus, find the area of the first quadrant part, multiply by $4$.  For the integration let $x=8\sin^3\theta$.

Comment: The shape in question is a special type of [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), called [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{8}\left(4-x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{2}3z^2(4-z^2)^{3/2}\,dz\\&=&192\int_{0}^{1}w^2(1-w^2)^{3/2}\,dw\\&=&96\int_{0}^{1}u^{1/2}(1-u)^{3/2}\,du\\&=&96\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(4)}\\&=&16\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\\&=&6\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\color{red}{6\pi}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: What substitution did you use for w->u? The left side decreased it's power by 4 but the right by two. Why?

Comment: @EpicatSupercell: I set $w=\sqrt{u}$, so $dw=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du$.

Comment: Then the resulting integral is a value for the Euler beta function.

Comment: Sadly the Euler beta function is outside the course material and couldn't be used during the test, will need a different solution then.

Comment: @EpicatSupercell: then set $w=\sin\theta$ and compute the resulting trigonometric integral through integration by parts or any other technique. It boils down to computing $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^6(\theta)\,d\theta$.